# Google map supports ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer from ESRI API?

Tags: google-maps, maps, esri, arcgis-server

i believe that in google API version 2, it could eventually call this method out. Moreover they do share or happen to be using the same type of coding.

However in version 3, i could not set this layer to the map neither via "layer.setMap(map)" because this esri method does not has this function , nor "map.addOverlay(layer)" because this function belongs to version 2 which has been taken down. can i ask what is the method replacing "map.addOverlay(layer)" in version 3. i have try using custom overlay function, but is comes out as a image which doesn't match the result i want.

** take note : ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer is to call a time aware data layer from esri

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these examples:
http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/arcgislink/docs/examples.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just wanted to let you know that simple links for answers are somewhat discouraged here. It would be more helpful if you provide context to which part of the link you think answers the question, and to actually quote that part in your answer. Websites come and go, but your answer will be here as long as Stack Overflow exists! Take a look at this helpful page on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, especially the heading "Provide context for links". Again, welcome to Stack Overflow!